# In Jquery Mobile How to show / hide an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I used this code to show / hide an `div`

```
$("[id*=viewMeButton]").click(function(){
     $("[id*=viewMe]").toggle();
     $("[id*=viewMeButton]").show(); 
});
```

like wise In Jquery Mobile it is possible to show / hide an HTML page.

For example in LinkedIn app.

In the LinkedIn mobile app if we click the `in` icon means it shows / hide an page. Like that i need.

Comment: do you mean show/hide an html page which is in an iframe in the same page..?

Comment: check out this link... This might help you... [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10953388/782145]

Comment: yes exactly i want to show /hide the HTML page on the same page.

Comment: check this fiddle. Is this the way you want.. http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/6UbGp/

Comment: @Philemon philip Kunjumon- in the fiddle they show / hide an div I want to show / hide an page. I need like LinkedIn mobile app if we click the in icon means it shows / hide an page. Like that i need

Answer (score 0):

```
$.mobile.changePage()
```

change from one page to another

```
$.mobile.loadPage()
```

Load an external page, enhance its content, and insert it into the DOM.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html